# Server-side Google API service request yields googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I've created service account credentials, running my code on a AWS instance.
Code is:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' ]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceAccount.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'app name'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
    settings._interpolation = configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
    settings.read('caremarkets.ini')
    origin_file_id = settings.get('GoogleSheetParams',''+manualType+'Manual2018')
    folderId = settings.get('GoogleSheetParams',''+manualType+'FolderID')
    timeStamp = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
    title = manualType+ " Userid: ( "+str(user_id)+" ) "+timeStamp

    fileObject= drive_service.files().copy(
          fileId=origin_file_id, body={"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",
                                 "id": folderId}], 'title': title}).execute()
```

however this is my error:   Where line 41  is the service call as in the above code fragment:

```
fileObject= drive_service.files().copy(
      fileId=origin_file_id, body={"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink",
                             "id": folderId}], 'title': title}).execute()
```

```
File "/home/ubuntu/dev_deploy/copy_master_spreadsheet_to_user_slave.py", line 41, in copy_master_spreadsheet_to_user_slave
    "id": folderId}], 'title': title}).execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 844, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1lNcqvQACH6DOBl3uQywJO1A6Iy6va7YdSrZiobMaOj0/copy?alt=json returned "File not found: 1lNcqvQACH6DOBl3uQywJO1A6Iy6va7YdSrZiobMaOj0">
```

Note that the above code will work fine locally on my machine.  Just getting this after I altered the code to use the service account and not the usual client_secret.json

Info on service account keys:

```
Service account name    Service account ID                                       Key ID                                         Key creation date   Options 
SACxxxxxxs              sacxxxxxxs@drivesheets-197604.iam.gserviceaccount.com    bf287f0baa29d4fa5f6b98aacf03b8bff13b0447       Mar 15, 2018
```

Thanks very much if you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file not found means just that the file id you have given doesn't exist or the user you are authenticated with doesn't have access to it.

take the service account email address and go to the web version of Google drive share the file with the service account.  it will then have access to the file in question.

Comment: DalmTo answered this to my satisfaction. To add a bit more information to the answer: 1.Logged into my email address that originated the file on Google Drive 2. Navigated to the folder that contains the file that had the http 404 3. Right clicked on that folder and selected "Share..." 4. On the Share with others dialog, entered the "service account ID" (that's the email address) for my "Service account name" and set the role for "Can organize, add & edit" (that's what I need)

Comment: @DalmTo and ElliotB, I tried your solution. does seem to resolve the issue. any ideas?

Comment: In my case, I don't have access to the folder where the file is supposed to be stored. I find it horrible as a end-user to have a "FileNotFound" error instead of a "Wrong permissions" error when the problem is a problem of permissions and not a problem of existence of the file..

Comment: @vinzee well telling a hacker that you dont have permissions is then telling them that the file does exist. Personally i think its better to say not found